# How to configure Asp.net indentity api to use existing users table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How managed to create an mvc 4 application using the templates builtin vs2013.  I want to know how do I get it to login using my db? It appears to have created it's own db which isn't what I expected.  I want to this the new membership thingy in asp.net 4.5

Comment: Do you want to use some specific tables you already have or you just want the identity tables deployed to a certain database?

Comment: I want to use my existing db schema. IT's your very basic username and password hash type login. It's a very small system with 2 user roles admin and student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement your own identity provider and plug it into the identity system. There cannot be a prebuilt provider for your specific tables because there are infinite amounts of such tables. On the other hand if it is a new app you can just deploy the standard identity provider and just not use most of its capabilities.

Comment: OK Any information on how to configure the mvc application to use the custom provider? This is about as clear as mud on asp.net website since they haven't bothered updating their site when they release new version.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity - This article describes what to do. The new version just has more methods but you are likely to not implement them (throw NotImplementedException) anyway. On the other hand you probably won't get much from ASP.NET identity unless you care for at least roles. The only benefit you will have is that your code would authenticate via OWIN but chances are you don't really care about this either. If you need extremely simple authentication either use the Identity tables or don't use Identity.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps someone can correct me on this if am wrong. It would appear there's isn't a login provider that allows basic username and password login using an existing table. I'm now writing my own storage provider so it uses ny own database schema. They've designed it so you swap out the storage provider which could be useful for implementing ldap/Active Directory based authentication.

There is a already built implementation but to me it seems too convoluted if the system only requires a basic login. If you system has 50 modules and each has it's own permissions then perhaps you do need a claims based authentication system.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this is by using forms athentication. After checking if the user credentials are valid, you can create a cookie to sign the user in with the following code:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(dbUser.UserName, rememberMe);
```

To make this work, you will have to change your `Web.config` so the `authentication mode` is Forms. An example is:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" />
</authentication>
```

After you have made these changes, you should be able to sign in using your the values in your (custom) user table.

[More info on SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: ASP.NET Identity is a framework that provides an API for working with users and roles and an implementation of that API. His question is about configuring that framework.

Comment: I would be quite interested in a solution using the actual ASP.NET Identity Framework instead of the FormsAuthentication. I have had this problem in the past and solved it with my provided answer, which feels like a cheap workaround.